# Proving that f(z), bounded above by C|z|^n for some constant C, is a polynomial of degree at most n:

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I realized some crucial mistakes I had made when posting this question, so here is an edited version that is less wordy and hopefully a better question:

From using the Cauchy Integral Formula, and the usual $ML$ inequality / Cauchy estimates, I am able to show that the $(n+1)$st derivative goes to zero, as I let $R$ go to infinity.

I am not sure how to show that the rest of the higher derivatives are also zero, which would prove that $f$ must be a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

How can I carry out an induction on $n$?

Thanks,

Edit: Now I notice that, as n increases, I get even better estimates, e.g., the denominator changes to $R^{n+2}$ , $R^{n+3}$, ...

Is this enough to conclude that once I show one derivative goes to zero, all higher derivatives must go to zero also, as $R$ goes to infinity?

Comment: What is this "the derivatives go to zero" business? No, it's that the derivatives at $0$ are bounded by something tending to zero. Hence those derivatives at $0$ are zero. Hence the Taylor series at $0$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for the technical comment, @zhw.  I will try to remember this, when writing out my proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $z_0$, and any $k\ge0$, we have
$$f^{(n+k+1)}(z_0)=\frac{(n+k+1)!}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+k+2}}\,dz$$
where $C$ is a circle of radius $R$ centred at $z_0$.  On the contour $C$ we have
$$|z|\le|z-z_0|+|z_0|=R+|z_0|\ ,$$
and so
$$|f^{(n+k+1)}(z_0)|\le \frac{(n+k+1)!}{2\pi}2\pi R\frac{C(R+|z_0|)^n}{R^{n+k+2}}\ .$$
Now on the RHS we can let $R\to\infty$ while everything else remains fixed, so the expression tends to $0$ and hence
$$f^{(n+k+1)}(z_0)=0\ .$$
Since this is true for every $z_0$ we have $f^{(n+k+1)}(z)=0$ identically, that is, every derivative past the $n$th is zero everywhere.  So $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

**Comment**.  I think the point you are missing is that $z_0$ is arbitrary, so we are showing that derivatives are zero **everywhere**.

Comment: Excellent answer, @David.  Can I ask a follow-up question:  for this proof to work, are we assuming that f is an entire function? Since for an arbitrary z0, we need f to be analytic everywhere to make use of the Cauchy Integral Formula.  But I think that there are some books that show a more advanced version of the Cauchy Integral Formula that only requires f to be continuous.

Comment: Sorry -- maybe just continuous on the boundary*, but analytic inside.  But feel free to comment.  Thanks, @David.

Comment: I'm not aware of the version of CIF you refer to.  As far as I know, $f$ needs to be analytic on and inside $C$, and since we are letting $R\to\infty$, this means analytic everywhere.  But it is just barely possible ;-) that there is something I don't know....

Comment: haha...thanks so much, @David.